# Update plugin error

Tags: android

I'm new to android, so please bear with me if my question is stupid.

I have an android project built in older version of gradle. The app works fine when modifying code in existing activities, but whenever I create  a new activity, I get the following error:

```
Error:(77, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
Upgrade plugin to version 3.0.1 and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

This is the content of app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias ''
            keyPassword ''
            storeFile file('')
            storePassword ''
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
    repositories {

        jcenter()

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //Fast and simple data storage library for Android
    // compile project(':squarecamera')
    //  compile 'com.github.boxme:squarecamera:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.6'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'io.paperdb:paperdb:0.9'
    compile 'com.fabiendevos:nanotasks:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile project(':squarecamera')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

This is my project level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And my android studio version is 3.0.1.

When I update the plugin, I get a lot of compatibility issues.
Please help me resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: share your app gradle file. also delete build folder, clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: I updated the question to include the app level gradle content. Please find it.

Comment: Can you please post the system level gradle file and also mention the Android Studio version.

Comment: Dear Arbaz, my sincere apologies for replying late. Here is the project level gradle content:

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


And my android studio version is 3.0.1

Comment: Please check  it in the question if not clear here.